# App freezing when appending string in bufferedreader while trying to get php output

Tags: java, php, bufferedreader, stringbuilder, processbuilder

Im trying to code an app that starts a server using php binary. However when i read the output from the /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/php using a BufferedReader, my app is freezing while appending output lines in the while statement. How do i fix this?

```
as.copy("php", new File("/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp"));
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/chmod 744 /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/php");
new File("/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/php").setExecutable(true);
new File("/sdcard/PocketMine-MP/PocketMine-MP.phar").setExecutable(true);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/chmod -R 777 /sdcard/PocketMine-MP");
        
String[] startserver = {"/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/php","/sdcard/PocketMine-MP/PocketMine-MP.phar","eng"};
final ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(startserver);
processbuilder.directory(new File("/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp"));
processbuilder.environment().put("TMPDIR","/sdcard/PocketMine-MP/tmp");
processbuilder.redirectErrorStream();
        
java.lang.Process process = processbuilder.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8")); 
        
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while(br.readLine() != null){
    builder.append(br.readLine()+"\n");
}
t.append(builder);
}catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}           
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of a process apparently pausing some time after ProcessBuilder.start() is often related to your application not consuming the stdout and stderr streams as they are generated. You can test this quickly by directing them to a file and read from the files after `proc.waitFor` ends. Add:

```
File outf = new File(TEMPDIR, "run.out");
File errf = new File(TEMPDIR, "run.err");
pb.redirectOutput(outf);
pb.redirectError(errf);
```

If that works, keep using the file redirect or set up a Runnable/Thread to consume both of getInputStream / getErrorStream.